# Can one get the actual point size of a QML Label which uses fontSizeMode: Text.Fit?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML Label which looks like:

```
Label {
  id: itemACheck
  color: "#000000"
  text: "✔️"

  width: parent.height
  height: parent.height

  horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
  verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
  font.pointSize: 100
  font.bold: true

  fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
  minimumPointSize: 10
}
```

After the font size has been determined, is it possible for me to know the value?

I have tried using onCompleted

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log( itemACheck.font.pointSize );
}
```

but, it just logs the value of 100.

I added a button to see if onCompleted was still to early...

```
Button {
    text: "push me"

    onClicked: {
      console.log( "clicked" );
      console.log( itemACheck.font.pointSize );
    }
}
```

but, it still logs the value of 100.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get that information. What is the value in finding it?

Comment: I would like other fields to use the same point size and to use the point size in calculating other values.